# Blinking/flashing LED porch light

Tags: led

I have a pair of LED porch lights. One of them has started to flash/flicker. Do I need to replace it? It is not a bulb; it is built in. It is extremely cold out. Could that be a factor?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Are these lights on a switch, or a dimmer? Any chance that bumping the LED might cause/cure the problem? If so, then it's wiring rather than the fixture, and should be checked out quickly.

Comment: I have the same problem.  It flashes on a very regular cycle, probably twice per second.  No dimmer and it started without a change in wiring and bumping it or changes in temperature don't seem to change it. It had been working fine for years, I expect it's going bad although I would hope for longer life from LED.  Built in light means I have to replace the whole fixture too.

Comment: Duplicate of https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/184868/one-of-the-outdoor-garage-lights-in-continuously-flashing-when-turned-on-why-t ?

Comment: Have you tried swapping the bulbs between positions to see if the flickering follows the bulb?

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen and it turned out that there was an outdoor circuit with 12 outdoor coach lamps on it. Flashing meant "find the bad bulb". I wound up replacing all of the bulbs a few flashing sessions later as it often counted old bulbs with poor seating as bad. 
I prefer a non flashing system tbh.